# Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger, ubuntu-14.04

I'm getting the following error message when I try to open my web server's home page in a browser:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 169.53.245.85 Port 80
```

I'm running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 with Passenger 4.0.58.

Here's my site configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName localhost

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/passenger/myapp/public

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/home/passenger/myapp/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's some other data that might be helpful:

```
rails@production:/sbin$ ps -ef | grep apache
root     28075     1  0 20:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28081 28075  0 20:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28082 28075  0 20:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28083 28075  0 20:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28084 28075  0 20:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28085 28075  0 20:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28134 28075  0 20:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
rails    30258 19062  0 21:15 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache
rails@production:/sbin$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -V
[Sun Feb 08 21:15:10.917531 2015] [core:warn] [pid 30261] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Feb 08 21:15:10.917668 2015] [core:warn] [pid 30261] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Sun Feb 08 21:15:10.917691 2015] [core:warn] [pid 30261] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Sun Feb 08 21:15:10.917705 2015] [core:warn] [pid 30261] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Sun Feb 08 21:15:10.917732 2015] [core:warn] [pid 30261] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Feb 08 21:15:10.930731 2015] [core:warn] [pid 30261] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Feb 08 21:15:10.930953 2015] [core:warn] [pid 30261] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Feb 08 21:15:10.930981 2015] [core:warn] [pid 30261] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Sun Feb 08 21:15:10.931039 2015] [so:warn] [pid 30261] AH01574: module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

Here's line 74 from apache2.conf:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
```

Here's the permissions for the app's folder:

```
rails@production:/home/passenger$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 18 www-data www-data 4096 Feb  6 18:20 myapp
```

Here's the envvars file where I thought the variables were being set correctly:

```
# Since there is no sane way to get the parsed apache2 config in scripts, some
# settings are defined via environment variables and then used in apache2ctl,
# /etc/init.d/apache2, /etc/logrotate.d/apache2, etc.
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
# temporary state file location. This might be changed to /run in Wheezy+1
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2/apache2$SUFFIX.pid
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
# Only /var/log/apache2 is handled by /etc/logrotate.d/apache2.
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
```

I've been fiddling with this one for a while to no avail. I thought the www-data user's permissions have been set correctly, which is what I thought would be wrong. I'm not sure what's going on with the errors that apache is spitting out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have any files in the myapp/public directory?
To see the directory listing, you need Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks

Without this config variable, if there are no files, you will get an error.
Most websites have:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php welcome.html  to limit access in this dir.

Comment: I have these files in my public directory: 404.html  422.html  500.html  favicon.ico  robots.txt. It's a Rails app. I'm able to boot it successfully, but I've had to luck with Passenger. I added the Option Indexes FollowSymLinks and now I see a file directory with those files in it vs. the forbidden error message.